# Extract multiple IPv4 addresses from single field separated by ","

Tags: regex, extract, pcre, ipv4

I'm tryin to extract multiple IPv4 addresses from a single field that are separated by ","

Example string: "badips":["123.456.789.12","123.456.789.13","123.456.789.14"]

Expected output of field *badips* with values 123.456.789.12 123.456.789.13 123.456.789.14

`^[^\[\n]*\["(?P<badips>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)` gets me the first IP
`^[^\[\n]*\["(?P<badips>.*?)\"]` gets me 123.456.789.12","123.456.789.13","123.456.789.14 with the "," in between.

I'm trying to come up with something dynamic because there will be atleast 1 IP in the field, but there could be more. ] will always follow the last IP

I'm new to regex and any help will be greatly appreciated. I have a regex cheat sheet and have been working at this all day, just can't seem to get it

Comment: If you can be specific about the regex flavor (ERE, PCRE, PCRE2, etc.) and/or your using language, you will have appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx for an IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890789/regex-for-an-ip-address) or one of the many other questions/answers with this search: [`[regex] "IP address"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+%22IP+address%22)

Comment: Or perhaps one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841454/regex-to-match-multiple-subnets-delimited-by-a-space, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972885/regex-to-match-multiple-ipaddress-domainnames-delimited-by-a-space, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268391/multiple-matches-with-delimiter

Comment: Start by creating a regex that matches a single valid IP (you can find this on Google _very_ easily). Then make a method to split the string on commas to separate all your IP addresses. Finally run through each IP address you separated and match it up against your regex to see if it's valid. If your IP's are actually inside JSON then use a JSON parser to get them out.

Comment: There is no way to do it with just regex. If you do it in Splunk, do it in two steps: `rex field=_raw "\["(?<badips>.*?)"]" | makemv delim="\x22,\x22" _raw`

Answer (score -1):

You should use capture groups:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})+
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pEsRsD/1)

Additional information about your implementation (language, regex flavor) will help us give you a better answer.